# Count positions in each team

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot

I want to get name of team and the number of each position in each team:

```
name|SG(position name)|PG(position name)|C(position name)|<br>
AAA |   1             | 2               |  4<br>
BBB |   2             | 2               |1<br>
```

TEAM table

```
TEAM_ID NUMBER
NAME    VARCHAR
```

PLAYER table

```
PLAYER_ID NUMBER
F_NAME    VARCHAR
L_NAME    VARCHAR
TEAM_ID NUMBER <- REFERENCE TEAM TABLE
POSITION VARCHAR <- LIKE SG, C, PG and other 5 or 6 positions
```

I wrote some code but can not figure out how to create position name columns which shows the number of position in each team. I found "pivot" for it but can not write query to get the desired result.

```
select team.name, (HOW TO WRITE QUERY?)
from player p
join team t on p.team_id = t.team_id
```

Comment: This is nothing you would normally do with SQL. You would do this in your app or Website instead where you care about how to dsplay the data. SQL is merely about what to display. A SQL query results in before-known columns. So if you know the position names, you can do this in SQL. If they are dynamic, you can't. Again, from your app, you can of course run a query to get you all possible positions and then build a second query that gets you all the data with one column per position. This is called dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick.

```
Select t.name,
Sum(case when p.position = 'SG' then 1 else 0 end) as SG,
Sum(case when p.position = 'PG' then 1 else 0 end) as PG,
Sum(case when p.position = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as C
From player p
Join team t using (team_id)
Group by t.name
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

EDIT:

Okay, I think I got it.

```
Select * from (
    Select t.name, p.position, p.player_id 
    From player p
    Join team t using (team_id)
)
Pivot XML
(
         Count(player_id)
         For position in (select position from player)
)
```

Comment: Position is not only 3 types, around 7 positions so that I don't want to use case when statement...

Comment: I added pivoting to my answer.

Comment: Hi,I'm sorry for replying you many times. I executed your code but I got error: ORA-00936: missing expression